# typescript: implementing an interface using specific objects as a function arg

Tags: typescript, object, interface

It's easier to explain this by looking at the actual code:

```
interface FooInterface {
  bar: (flags: { [key: string]: string }) => void;
}

export class Foo implements FooInterface {
  bar(flags: { myFlag: string }) {}
}
```

I want anyone who implements `FooInterface.bar` to pass an object. I don't care about the keys.

However, when I implemented it in `Foo` class and I named the key as `myFlag` I got an error that this key doesn't exist in the interface. See the complete error below.

How do I tell Typescript to ignore the keys in the implemented classes?

The error I got:

```
src/extensions/test/test.provider.ts:24:3 - error TS2416: Property 'bar' in type 'Foo' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'FooInterface'.
  Type '(flags: { myFlag: string; }) => void' is not assignable to type '(flags: { [key: string]: string; }) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'flags' and 'flags' are incompatible.
      Property 'myFlag' is missing in type '{ [key: string]: string; }' but required in type '{ myFlag: string; }'.

24   bar(flags: { myFlag: string }) {}
     ~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

Using generic typings, you can force the flags to be an object with string values, then specify the type in the class implementation:

```
interface FooInterface<T extends { [key: string]: string }> {
  bar: (flags: T) => void;
}

type BarFlags = { myFlag: string };

export class Foo implements FooInterface<BarFlags> {
  bar(flags: BarFlags) {}
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0ElzXkgHgBVkIAPSEAEwGdkBvZAbQGsIBPALmRrClADmAXW69+IAcgC+APgYAoZMgBGcKNwAUMADZwBNbkQCUyALxyAbumBUA3PKnz5YdgAcUAITWpd+sw2QAW3YfPVE+QWl7eXJXdCgwZARdGjoMdGRgQNdtCECIcDTMHEhYRAgCLyhQ-Tl6RRU1LV8DZCqamhN6RykgA)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are saying `myFlag` must be a `string`, but the type `{ [key: string]: string }` does not guarantee that the `myflag` key actually exists. So it cannot satisfy the `string` type.

If you make the `myFlag` key optional it works, you then just have to check it for existence.

```
interface FooInterface {
  bar: (flags: { [key: string]: string }) => void;
}

export class Foo implements FooInterface {
  bar(flags: { myFlag?: string }) {
    if (flags.myFlag) {
      console.log(flags.myFlag) // logs a string
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0ElzXk5AbwChlkAjOKALmQAoYAbOAcwGdbDkBtAawgCetNmCigWAXWGjxyAL4BKZAF4AfMgBu6YABMA3MTnFiEAB4AHdFDDIEzNmzSZkwALbnGEVxHCOM2XFhEFBIySigGZnZOZFcBVCiAfmkxEBZ5JVCyFxh6JlY2ADo4hNZM0myyBHQQNnRPQsZ0FkiC4viopQB6LuQm9mQ4ZBFUlgqyIwnDIA)

---

If you want to enforce that `myFlag` is provided when you call `bar` is the `Foo` class, then @leonardfactory's answer is what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I'm probably going to use both approaches yours and @leonardfactory depends on the circumstances. (so no idea whom I should mark as accepted :/). The part that confuses me is that I was under the impression that an Interface can be general and the implementation can be more specific and that's not the case here.